# May I have some suggestion on inexpensive robotic arm?

Tags: robotic-arm

I want to build some simple application. I need a 5 or 6 degrees of freedom robotic arm. The arm must have feedback, so that I can control it preciously. The arm must be able to handle at least 5 lbs. And the arm would be able to work 10 hours a day.

My budget is USD$300 . Any suggestion?

Comment: Welcome to *robotics* Marco, but I'm afraid that *[shopping questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)* really aren't a good fit for a stack exchange site. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*. Take a look at [ask] and [about] for more information on how stack exchange works.

Comment: You may want to try explaining your problem. It *may* be that a cheap robotic arm is the best solution, but it may be that people here might be able to suggest other options, which might suit your budget. As it is, without details of the required working envelope, this question is impossible to answer. A 5lb load in a 10cm radius area is *much* easier than a 5lb load in a 50cm radius area for instance. Also, working 10 hours a day at what sort of cycle time? A pick and place every 10 minutes is very different to a pick and place every 10 seconds.

Comment: Although this does not belong here, I would love to see an answer for this.

Comment: Once this is no long "On hold", I have a suggestion for the arm.